# Make nbr2mp4 work in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, webex

I am trying to convert .arf file to mp4. This requires the utility nbr2mp4 converter. I downloaded it from [here](https://www.webex.co.in/support/downloads.html#)

Following the instructions, I was not able to convert the .arf file to mp4. I found that it is because I don't have all the required libraries for running the script.

I still need `libwbxbase.so`.

How do I get this library?

Comment: You do not need to install an external `libwbxbase.so` as this is a part of the downloaded and installed nbr2mp4 archive. Can you post your .arf file perhaps here: http://www.datafilehost.com/ and I will right up a formal conversion answer.

Comment: [download link](https://www.datafilehost.com/d/d224bfee) It is class about data structures. Thanx for the help

Comment: Thanks for that, I have failed to get this converted so far despite my confidence. Sigh....

Comment: Well let it be. Thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-0 libwxbase3.0-0-dbg libwxbase3.0-0-dev
```

This should install `libwbxbase.so`

Comment: Right now im away from my laptop, I will try it once I reach home. Does the version matter? All the other libraries were version 1.0

Comment: This is version 3.0.

Comment: The last libwxbase3.0-0-dev was not found. But libwxbase3.0-dev was there. I installed it but still libwxbase.so is not found

Comment: What is the output of apt-file libwbxbase.so

Comment: It doesnt output anything. ubashu thanks for the help. I will just one of my friends windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

The libwbxbase.so is part of the nbr2_mp4 package.
You could copy the file to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu or anywhere where your executable is picking up other libraries from - to know this execute ldd nbr_play it will tell you the paths of all the libraries the executable is picking up from.